# CsvDownloader leaves data empty

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using react-csv-downloader, everything worked fine when following the setup from its instruction pages, however, I want to use variable data now and this does not seem to work as expected.

**What am I trying**
my CsvDownloader itself:

```
<CsvDownloader datas={datas.current} filename="AdminPerMonth">
    <button>Download</button>
</CsvDownloader>
```

I use an useEffect to get the wanted data upon starting

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/transformDataToCSV', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json',
        },
    }).then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            datas.current = data.rows             
            console.log(datas.current)})
},[])
```

and the variable itself:

```
const datas = useRef(null);
```

my data from the console log looks like this:
[image]

**Current error**
When I run the code like this, I receive the following error:

```
csv.ts:32 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of null
    at extractHeaderFromData (csv.ts:32)
    at csv.ts:122
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (csv.ts:118)
    at step (index.tsx:24)
    at Object.next (index.tsx:24)
    at index.tsx:24
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at push../node_modules/react-csv-downloader/dist/lib/csv.js.__awaiter (index.tsx:24)
    at Object.csv [as default] (csv.ts:116)
    at CsvDownload.<anonymous> (index.tsx:34)
    at step (index.js:600)
    at Object.next (index.js:600)
    at index.js:600
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at push../node_modules/react-csv-downloader/dist/index.js.__awaiter (index.js:600)
    at CsvDownload._this.handleClick (index.tsx:32)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:292)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:306)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:389)
    at executeDispatchesInOrder (react-dom.development.js:411)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (react-dom.development.js:3278)
    at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:3287)
    at forEachAccumulated (react-dom.development.js:3259)
    at runEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js:3304)
    at runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js:3514)
    at handleTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:3558)
    at batchedEventUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:21871)
    at batchedEventUpdates (react-dom.development.js:795)
    at dispatchEventForLegacyPluginEventSystem (react-dom.development.js:3568)
    at attemptToDispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:4267)
    at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:4189)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:653)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11039)
    at discreteUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:21887)
    at discreteUpdates (react-dom.development.js:806)
    at dispatchDiscreteEvent (react-dom.development.js:4168)
```

**What have I tried as well**
I have tried with adding headers, setting them both the same in the datas.current part and const headers, this resulted in the CSV file being created but only containing the headers and not the data.

**What do I want?**
I want the data what is currently written under datas.current to actually appear in the csv file when downloading it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that the csv downloader is rendering with the current value of datas (which is null) before the fetch request is finished, and useRef does not cause a re-render, so its still using the null value even after the request is finished.

Switching datas to a state variable or adding a state variable to determine if that data has loaded

```
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    if(!loaded){
      fetch('/transformDataToCSV', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json',
        },
      }).then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            datas.current = data.rows  
            setLoaded(true);           
            console.log(datas.current)})
     }
  },[])
```

should solve the issue.